# Why connection is timed out in Javamail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use javamail in eclipse to send out an email via gmail. Each time I get javax.mail.MessagingException

**Exception**

```
 DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
    DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 

smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

**Code**

```
package org.itc.utility;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.itc.model.User;

public class SendEmail {
    public User sendingEmail(User user)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();  
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);  
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 587);  
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        Session mailSession = null;

        mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,  
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                return new PasswordAuthentication("<yogeshvbhat@gmail.com>", "<zc516z918>");  
            }  
        });  


        try {


            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            message.setSubject("Sample Subject");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yogeshvbhat@gmail.com"));
            String []to = new String[]{"yogeshyvb@gmail.com"};
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[0]));
            String body = "Sample text";
            message.setContent(body,"text/html");
            transport.connect();

            transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println(exception);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Each time it is skipping the try block and I'm getting the exception. Any help on this?

Comment: Check your server firewall's settings.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique, Firewall is disabled

Answer (score 1):

In general there are a few possible reasons for a connection timeout, including the server being offline, network link failure and networking routing problems<sup>1</sup>.

But in this case, the most likely explanation is that a firewall is blocking your out-going access to the gmail mail server.  This is often done as a means of monitoring / controlling an organization's out-going email, or as a way of preventing deliberate SPAMing or SPAMing by compromised machines.

> Firewall is disabled

It is probably not your computer's firewall or your (home) network's firewall doing the blocking.  It is likely to be blocked by your organization's network admins, or your ISP's admins.

---

<sup>1 - In general, these things are likely to disrupt all network traffic from your machine to the server, so it is worth doing some probing with "ping", "traceroute", "tcptraceroute", etcetera.</sup>

Comment: Also, here's some [connection debugging tips from the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Answer (score 0):

**Add only these properties:**

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

**Also, check your gmail settings:**

[Set up 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en&rd=1)

Comment: None of that would fix a connect timeout, and you haven't explained why it would.